# Angular - Toggle Content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4 and I am trying to toggle contenteditable="true" / contenteditable="false"

I've got this:

```
<h1 (dblclick)="edit($event)" contentEditable="true">Double-click Here to edit</h1>
```

or I could also have a checkbox if its easier to toggle edit mode?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" (onchange)="edit($event)">Toggle Edit mode
```

and on the .ts file:

```
edit(event) {
    // code here needed
  }
```

Comment: How you are going to edit in a <h1> tag?

Comment: @Vega with the [contentEditable attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the following.

## HTML

```
<h4 (dblclick)="contentEditable=true; toto.focus()"
    *ngIf="!contentEditable">
  {{myText}}
</h4>
<input #toto
       autofocus
       *ngIf="contentEditable"
       [value]="myText"
       (keyup.enter)="contentEditable=false; save(toto.value)"
       (blur)="contentEditable=false; save(toto.value)"
       type="text">
```

## TypeScript

```
myText = "Double-click Here to edit";
```

With some css you can get to have one in place of the other.

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TtXMORsMxOqsLCqKai2y?p=preview)

Comment: Its a good idea but when you double click the input is empty and what you type is not changed. Do I need to add code to the .ts file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: The text is not changed after you blur

Comment: It does'nt need to save anyway just to retain the new value after blur

Comment: I did update the plunker to retain the value after the blur or enter key

Answer (score 2):

Create a one way binding from the contentEditable property to a field in your Component, then add an event binding for the click event on the header.

In your component, create a boolean:

```
private isEditable = false;
```

Then, in your html, toggle the value of this boolean with a click event, and bind the `contentEditable` property to this boolean as well:

```
<h1 (dblclick)="isEditable = !isEditable" [contentEditable]="isEditable">
```

You could also put the code of the `(dblclick)` binding inside a method on your component, if you'd rather have some method like `toggleIsEditable()`, with additional logic.

Comment: I am not sure this works, as the the editing mode is triggered on a simple click.

Comment: @Vega it works for what the OP was technically asking, but you are right that having to double click the element to turn on editable mode, then click **again** to edit is a weird behavior. Would work like this, though:
`<h1 (click) = "isEditable = true" (blur) = "isEditable = false [contentEditable]="isEditable" >`. Here's your plunker with this implementation: https://embed.plnkr.co/41u12Nu4vpXpKPtcZzEN/

Comment: Of course, all of this is assuming that the element need only be editable, not that the value of the element be stored in the component. If that were the case, a much more Angularly way to do this would be [(ngModel)].